# Exchanger Vs CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I was wondering if anyone has used the java.util.concurrent.Exchanger class. According to java docs an Exchanger can be used to share some data between a pair for threads. The below sample is a typical usecase of reading and writing data and interaction between threads.

```
class FillAndEmpty {
   Exchanger<DataBuffer> exchanger = new Exchanger<DataBuffer>();
   DataBuffer initialEmptyBuffer = ... a made-up type
   DataBuffer initialFullBuffer = ...

   class FillingLoop implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
       DataBuffer currentBuffer = initialEmptyBuffer;
       try {
         while (currentBuffer != null) {
           addToBuffer(currentBuffer);
           if (currentBuffer.isFull())
             currentBuffer = exchanger.exchange(currentBuffer);
         }
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ... }
     }
   }

   class EmptyingLoop implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
       DataBuffer currentBuffer = initialFullBuffer;
       try {
         while (currentBuffer != null) {
           takeFromBuffer(currentBuffer);
           if (currentBuffer.isEmpty())
             currentBuffer = exchanger.exchange(currentBuffer);
         }
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
     }
   }

   void start() {
     new Thread(new FillingLoop()).start();
     new Thread(new EmptyingLoop()).start();
   }
 }
```

The same could have been done with two CountDownLatch s. One for writing to Buffer and one to notify the writer once all the reader threads have processed the records. So my question is

1. What is the ideal use of Exchanger
2. What are its pros and cons over say a CountDownLatch

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you get on top is a guarantee of a `happens-before` relationship, that is that everything thread A did to the exchanged object will be visible by thread B and vice versa. And as its name suggests, it exchanges objects between threads, processing both directions in one call. It represents a more specialised but higher level operation than a countdown latch.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop. I guess what I can take from this is though the same thing could have been achieved via Latches or Semaphores, Exhangers are specific for this kind of work provided it's not a big issue in sharing a data container between reader n writer threads.

Comment: @Taffa This is my take on it at least but as a disclaimer I have to say that I've never used `Exchanger`s in anger. There may easily be some important detail that I've overlooked.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not the slightest idea of how you can implement what an `Exchanger` does using a `CountDownLatch`. If you think that there is an alternative way of implementing that code example using another technology, then *prove it*. Maybe you discover the worth of `Exchanger` while trying that.

Answer (score 1):

[`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is a synchronization mechanism. You initialize an instance to a fixed count value N, then await until some other threads decrement this counter to 0. Its often used to make a thread wait for other N different threads to complete. But of course there are many other applications.

[`Exchanger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) is a communication mechanism. It lets you pass an object from thread T1 to T2 and at the same time pass back an object from T2 to T1. The swapping is blocking so you can use it as a synchronization mechanism as well, but this is not what it is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

With CountDownLatches, you have to place references to buffers somewhere so that they are accessible to both threads (or pass references to the constructors). This increases the size of program code.
Then, you have to recreate CountDownLatch for each transaction.

Other approaches are:

- use pair of Semaphores instead of CountDownLatches - need not to recreate
- use pair of ArrayBlockingQueues - need not to recreate, need not to worry about references to bufferes, and better parallelism than when using Exchanger.

UPDT
Exchanger is a pair of blocking queues of size 1 each, with single operation `exhange` which is equivalent to `queue1.put(value); return queue2.take();`. So the only case when its using is justified, is when you need a pair of blocking queues of size 1 and always call put and get simultaneously. This is a rare case and I cannot see a reason why it was included in the standard java library.

Comment: Thanks @Alexei for your suggestions. Since this typical use case can be implemented by so many ways , I was wondering is there a use case where Exchanger is better than most other solutions?

Comment: @Tatha Don't underestimate the value of simplicity. Exchangers are very simple and straightforward to use. The downside is that it solves a very specialised problem.